# Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, axios

I am using axios to access the backend when a user registers, it takes their name, email, and password and dispatches REGISTER_SUCCESS when they are successful. When a user fails to register, it dispatches. for dispatch am using redux thunk as middleware so i can write dispatch in arrow function REGISTER_FAILURE, but instead gets the error below. This is stated in the webpack documentation.

> topLevelAwait: Support the Top Level Await Stage 3 proposal, it makes
> the module an async module when await is used on the top-level. And it
> is enabled by default when experiments.futureDefaults is set to true.

But I don't know how to implement this code. I have tried react-scripts webpack.config.js file, but I get another error. Can you please help?

**ERROR IN CONSOLE**

```
ERROR in ./src/action/auth.js
    [1] Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
    [1] File was processed with these loaders:
    [1]  * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
    [1]  * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
    [1]  * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
    [1] You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
    [1] Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
    [1]     at C:\Users\krish\OneDrive\Desktop\udemy learning 2\dev-connector\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\HarmonyDetectionParserPlugin.js:54:11
    [1]     at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Users\krish\OneDrive\Desktop\udemy learning 2\dev-connector\client\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:16)
    [1]     at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (C:\Users\krish\OneDrive\Desktop\udemy learning 2\dev-connector\client\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    [1]     at JavascriptParser.walkAwaitExpression (C:\Users\krish\OneDrive\Desktop\udemy learning 2\dev-connector\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptParser.js:2337:29)
    [1]     at JavascriptParser.walkExpression (C:\Users\krish\OneDrive\Desktop\udemy learning 2\dev-connector\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptParser.js:2267:10)
    [1]     at JavascriptParser.walkVariableDeclaration (C:\Users\krish\OneDrive\Desktop\udemy learning 2\dev-connector\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptParser.js:2121:33)
    [1]     at JavascriptParser.walkStatement (C:\Users\krish\OneDrive\Desktop\udemy learning 2\dev-connector\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptParser.js:1615:10)
    [1]     at JavascriptParser.walkStatements (C:\Users\krish\OneDrive\Desktop\udemy learning 2\dev-connector\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptParser.js:1476:9)
    [1]     at C:\Users\krish\OneDrive\Desktop\udemy learning 2\dev-connector\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptParser.js:1650:9
    [1]     at JavascriptParser.inBlockScope (C:\Users\krish\OneDrive\Desktop\udemy learning 2\dev-connector\client\node_modules\webpack\lib\javascript\JavascriptParser.js:3108:3)
    [1]
    [1] ERROR in [eslint]
    [1] src\action\auth.js
    [1]   Line 14:31:  Unexpected use of 'name'   no-restricted-globals
    [1]   Line 14:37:  'email' is not defined     no-undef
    [1]   Line 14:44:  'password' is not defined  no-undef
    [1]   Line 17:52:  'config' is not defined    no-undef
    [1]   Line 18:3:   'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef
    [1]   Line 26:29:  'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef
    [1]   Line 28:3:   'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef
      },
```

**AUTH.JS FILE**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { SET_ALERT } from './types';
import { REGISTER_FAILURE, REGISTER_SUCCESS } from './types';

// Register
export const register =
  ({ name, email, password }) =>
  async dispatch => {
    const config = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
  };

const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });

try {
  const res = await axios.post('/api/users', body, config);
  dispatch({
    type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    payload: res.data,
  });
} catch (err) {
  const errors = err.response.data.errors;

  if (errors) {
    errors.forEach(error => dispatch(SET_ALERT(error.msg, 'danger')));
  }
  dispatch({
    type: REGISTER_FAILURE,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the axios because  we don't need a config object for axios as the default headers in axios are already Content-Type: application/json also axios stringifies and parses JSON for you, so no need for JSON.stringify or JSON.parse

**there is no need to write config file default headers in axios are already Content-Type: application/json**

```
export const register =
  ({ name, email, password }) =>
  async dispatch => {
    const config = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
  };

const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });
```

**change my code to this here formdata contains email,name and password**

```
export const register = (formData) => async dispatch => {
 try {
   const res = await axios.post('/api/users',formData);
   dispatch({
     type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
     payload: res.data,
   });
 } catch (err) {
   const errors = err.response.data.errors;

   if (errors) {
     errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
   }
   dispatch({
     type: REGISTER_FAILURE,
   });
 }
}
```